# Why the Jquery Autocomplete is not working if css is present

Tags: css

I am trying to put a autocomplete functionality on a text input , this is working fine if css is not present but if css is present this is not working .

This is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1jj5vd14/2/)

and this is my code

```
var sourcesymbols = ["ONE", "TWO", "THREE"];

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  $("#stock_name").autocomplete({
    source: sourcesymbols,
    messages: {
        noResults: '',
        results: function() {}
    }
});

});
```

Could you please let me know how to resolve this .

Comment: You need to a) put the relevant code in your question and b) work on narrowing down the problem. Your fiddle has a wall of CSS and you know that it's the issue, so you should spend some time removing or changing your CSS rules to see what's causing the issue. None of us wants to wade through that huge set of selectors.

Comment: If you consideer your css relevant, why don't you share it?

Answer (score 0):

when you use CSS styling for the text box you will hide the data list (auto complete list data) you can try an alternative as shown in this link - [Datalist](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/creating-autocomplete-dropdowns-datalist-element)